# Как подключиться по ssh к серверу, запущенному в VirtualBox, через NAT?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, nat

Как подключиться по ssh к серверу, запущенному в VirtualBox, через NAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как подключиться по ssh к серверу, запущенному на виртуальной машине в VirtualBox, через NAT?

Пусть имя машины - x. Тогда команды

```
VBoxManage setextradata x "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/Protocol" TCP  
VBoxManage setextradata x "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/GuestPort" 22  
VBoxManage setextradata x "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/HostPort" 2222
```

настроят отображение портов на гостевую машину. И по команде

```
ssh root@localhost -p 2222
```

можно будет подключиться к серверу, запущенному на гостевой машине.

Answer (score 2):

и запускать полезно в "безголовом" (без GUI) режиме:

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html

> To start a virtual machine with
> VBoxHeadless, you have three options:
>
> You can use
>
> ```
> VBoxManage startvm "VM name" --type headless
> ```
>
> The extra --type option causes
> VirtualBox to use VBoxHeadless as the
> front-end to the internal
> virtualization engine instead of the
> Qt front-end.
>
> One alternative is to use VBoxHeadless
> directly, as follows:
>
> ```
> VBoxHeadless --startvm <uuid|name>
> ```
>
> This way of starting the VM helps
> troubleshooting problems reported by
> VBoxManage startvm ... because you can
> see sometimes more detailed error
> messages, especially for early
> failures before the VM execution is
> started. In normal situations
> VBoxManage startvm is preferred since
> it runs the VM directly as a
> background process which has to be
> done explicitly when directly starting
> VBoxHeadless.
>
> The other alternative is to start
> VBoxHeadless from the VirtualBox
> Manager GUI, by holding the Shift key
> when starting a virtual machine.
>
> Note that when you use VBoxHeadless to
> start a VM, since the headless server
> has no other means of output, the VRDP
> server will always be enabled,
> regardless of whether you had enabled
> the VRDP server in the VM's settings.
> If this is undesirable (for example
> because you want to access the VM via
> ssh only), start the VM like this:
>
> ```
> VBoxHeadless --startvm <uuid|name> --vrde off
> ```
>
> To have the VRDP server enabled
> depending on the VM configuration, as
> the other front-ends would, use this:
>
> ```
> VBoxHeadless --startvm <uuid|name> --vrde config
> ```
>
> If you start the VM with VBoxManage
> startvm ... then the configuration
> settings of the VM are always used.